# Unexpected token ILLEGAL in javascript for array

Tags: javascript

```
var list =["<script></script>", "A", "B", "C"]
```

I got unexpected token ILLEGAL error here. Say, if I do want the script tag to be included, but just plain text, how can I format the list. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? That should execute just fine in a browser.

Comment: The browser is mangling it. Break the "script" string up into two concact peices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using an inline script<sup>1</sup>, then `</script>` will terminate the script element in the middle of the array constructor (all the HTML is parsed before the text nodes in the element are passed to the JS engine, `</script>` gets no special treatment for being inside a JS string literal).

Escape the `/`:

```
var list =["<script><\/script>", "A", "B", "C"]
```

You could also move the script to an external file and `src` it.

1. i.e. a `<script>` element with the JS directly inside it as opposed to one with a `src` attribute or an intrinsic event attribute like `onclick`.

Comment: I am trying to use this one right now: var list = [&quot;&lt;script&gt;&lt;&#47;script&gt;&quot;, &quot;A&quot;, &quot;B&quot;, &quot;C&quot;], it gives me an error of "unexpected token &". Any further explanation why this does not work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Replace with

```
var list =["<script></"+"script>", "A", "B", "C"]
```

The `"</script>"` was ending the script element in which you have your script.

Comment: Splitting the string into two parts and concatenating them is marginally less efficient and a fair bit less readable then just escaping the `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Need to escape   the `</script>"`  tag

```
<\/script>"

var list =["<script><\/script>", "A", "B", "C"];
```

Otherwise it tends to see it as the end of the script tag ..