# How to initialize string with </script> tag in JavaScript without splitting it or adding backlash before slash </script>

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problem with  tag once I want to intialize it into String. 
Before posting this question< I have looked several already asked questions regarding closing  tag in string:

- [The string "</script>" in an array is interpreted, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19221841/7186690)
- [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236073/7186690)
- [Unexpected token ILLEGAL in javascript for array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13349649/7186690)

But, in my case, I cannot slipt  into two parts like:

```
var test = '...... </scr'+'ipt>......';
```

Because, I receive it from Backend directly as one variable, I want to do it in Frontend without touching representation of  in Backend.

```
<body>
   <p id="one">This is a text</p>

   <script type="text/javascript">

     var some = '<script>alert(\"from Learning objective title\")</script>';

     document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = some;

  </script>
</body>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape double quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: How are you receiving it from the back-end? The issue only affects JavaScript literals in `<script>` tags, not data received other ways.

Comment: hm, yeah, I am wrong and I understood that there is no way to initialize whole string with </script> tag then escape </script> tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

It has to be escaped **before** being inserted into the HTML document.

This is a fundamental feature of how escaping works.